# Android Phonegap database

Tags: android, database, cordova

I'm using the following code to get data from a database and display the contents in a listview. But I don't want to create a database each time the app is loaded... I want to create it just once... But whenever the app is closed, the database is deleted. I want it to stay so that I can add data the next time without creating it.

```
var arr = new Array();
var a;
var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);
db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCBc);
function populateDB(tx) {
  tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CUSTOMER');
  tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CUSTOMER (phno unique, fname, mname, lname, address, email)');
  tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (phno, fname, mname, lname, address, email) VALUES (16, "shank","p","ram","addresssss","emailaddress")');
};
function queryDB(tx) {
  tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
}
function querySuccess(tx, results) {
  var len = results.rows.length;
  for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
    $('#home').append('<li><a href="#artists">'+results.rows.item(i).phno+'<br>'+results.rows.item(i).fname+'</a></li>').listview("refresh");
  }
};
function errorCB(err) {
  console.log("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
}
function successCBc() {
  var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);
  db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the line from your code, it works!!

tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CUSTOMER');

Answer (score 0):

As per your code you are dropping table on populateDB(). Try removing the following line from populateDB() and check the database status again.

```
tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CUSTOMER');
```

Also either remove unique constraint from the table create script replace existing code with following with following

```
var randomId = new Date().getTime();
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (phno unique, fname, mname, lname, address, email) VALUES ("'+ randomId +'", "shank","p","ram","addresssss","emailaddress")');
```

Also check that the jQuery Mobile library is properly loaded otherwise it will print only the first record and then stop execution.

Comment: shows all the records for me. let me put the entire code in answer

Comment: check this fiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/dhavaln/DFUNK/](http://jsfiddle.net/dhavaln/DFUNK/)